# How to understand the time in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I put some data into elasticsearch. The mapping is like below:

```
"@timestamp": { "index": "not_analyzed", "type": "date"},
"ROUTER" : { "type" : "integer", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
"IN_IFACE" : { "type" : "integer", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
"OUT_IFACE" : { "type" : "integer", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
"SRC_MAC" : { "type" : "long", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
"DST_MAC" : { "type" : "long", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
"SRC_IP" : { "type" : "ip", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
"DST_IP" : { "type" : "ip", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
"BYTES" : { "type" : "long", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
"PACKETS" : { "type" : "long", "index" : "not_analyzed" }
```

The timestamp is from 1454256000 to 1454342400.

They should representing the time from 2016/02/01 00:00:00 to 2016/02/01 23:55:00.

But when I use below query to search. The return is not what I wanted.

```
curl -XPOST "127.0.0.1:9200/sflow_1454256000/sflow/_search?pretty" -d '
{
    "size":0,
    "query": {
        "filtered":{
            "filter":{
                "bool":{
                    "must":[                      
                        {"term":{"ROUTER":10002}},
                        {"term":{"IN_IFACE":2}}
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "by_minute": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "@timestamp",
            "interval": "5m"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "sum_bytes": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "BYTES"
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }
}'
{
  "took" : 459,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1150167,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "by_minute" : {
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key_as_string" : "1970-01-17T19:55:00.000Z",
        "key" : 1454100000,
        "doc_count" : 1150167,
        "sum_bytes" : {
          "value" : 3.450522575E9
        }
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can see that I want the value fall into one bucket for each 5 min. But now seems all data fall into one bucket and the time is not right either.

Can any one tell me why please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are apparently indexing time / 1000

```
1454256000/1000 = 1454256 -> Sat, 17 Jan 1970 19:57:36 GMT
1454342400/1000 = 1454342 -> Sat, 17 Jan 1970 19:59:02 GMT
```

that is why they all fall within the same bucket `1970-01-17T19:55:00.000Z`, corrisponding with your date interval / 1000

Comment: Yes. I found that the default format for timestamp in elasticsearch is epoch  millisecond. I was using the timestamp in seconds. I changed the mapping , use format epoch_second , it is ok now